# What’s the difference between nervous, anxious and fearful

Tags: vocabulary

All the three words seem to be interchangeable and I have searched Cambridge Dictionary and Oxford Dictionaries.
Oxford Dictionaries link:
https://www.lexico.com/definition/nervous
https://www.lexico.com/definition/anxious
https://www.lexico.com/definition/fearful
Cambridge Dictionary Link:
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nervous?q=Nervous
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/anxious
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fearful
When can these three words and other words relating to “fear” used?Are they interchangeable?

Comment: These words are not generally interchangeable but you have the definitions.  What about them is confusing you?

Comment: _Nervous_ and _anxious_ are very similar in meaning; you can be nervous/anxious about a forthcoming event, or have a nervous temperament. _Fearful_ implies that there is some definite thing to be afraid of.

Comment: @jwh20 For example, I have stage fright.So do I say that I am nervous or anxious?That was what was confusing all the while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 1-10, nervous is the least, followed by worried then anxious being the worst.
Usually, nervous is like you are scared that something would frighten you. Talking about frightened, it is about being scarier than nervous. Worried is used to describe that someone had not arrived and you are worried. Anxious, on the other hand, is like that you know something bad has happened and you are worried.

Comment: What about other words that mean fearful?Could you attach a picture  that states the intensity of all the synonyms of the word”fear”?Or something like a word thermometer?